# Prove that $(A \cap B)^\circ = A^\circ \cap B^\circ$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $A, B \subset X$

How can I show that  $(A \cap B)^\circ = A^\circ \cap B^\circ$ ?

Please just tell me a Hint. ($A^\circ$ and $B^\circ$ are sets of interior points of A and B)

Comment: Mathdude,   A° is the "interior of A".  A and B are NOT 'sets of interior points".  A° is the set of interior points of A and B° is the set of interior points of B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to prove is that:

1. $V^{\circ}$ is an open set
2. $V^{\circ}=V$ if and only if $V$ is open
3. If $V \subset W$ then $V^{\circ} \subset W^{\circ}$

which follows directly from the definition of interior of a set. Once this is done the demonstration is as follows:

> First note that $A^{\circ} \subset A$ and $B^{\circ} \subset B$, then
>   $A^{\circ} \cap B^{\circ} \subset A \cap B$.
>
> As $A^{\circ}$ and $B^{\circ}$ are both open their intersection is
>   also open, i.e, $A^{\circ} \cap B^{\circ}$ is open and by (2) we get
>
> $(A^{\circ} \cap B^{\circ})^{\circ}=A^{\circ} \cap B^{\circ}$ .
>
> By (3) we have that  $A^{\circ} \cap B^{\circ} \subset A \cap B$ implies that
>
> $(A^{\circ} \cap B^{\circ})^{\circ} \subset (A \cap B) ^{\circ}$
>
> but we have seen that $(A^{\circ} \cap B^{\circ})^{\circ}=A^{\circ} \cap B^{\circ}$ . So,
>
> $A^{\circ} \cap B^{\circ} \subset( A \cap B)^{\circ} $.
>
> Conversely,using (3) we have that $A\cap B \subset A$ implies $(A\cap B)^{\circ} \subset
>  A^{\circ}$ and similarly $(A\cap B)^{\circ} \subset B^{\circ}$.
>
> Therefore we have that
>
> $(A\cap B)^{\circ} \subset A^{\circ} \cap B^{\circ}$
>
> So, we can conclude that
>
> $(A\cap B)^{\circ} =A^{\circ} \cap B^{\circ}$.

Comment: How is $A\cap B \subset A$ ?

Comment: By definition $x \in A \cap B$ means $x \in A$ and $x \in B$, so this implies directly that $x \in A$ and therefore we have that $A\cap B \subset A$.

Comment: yes sorry my brain had an error..

Comment: I dont see how you can conclude that $A \cap B$ is open

Comment: I never did that !!

Comment: So why you use $V = V°$ for any open set $V$?

Comment: I used that property with $A^{\circ} \cap B^{\circ}$, not with $A \cap B$.

Comment: Sorry, but why is it then $A \cap B$ ⊂ $(A \cap B)°$?

Comment: Again, I never used that in the proof.

Comment: Ok, then I just dont see how you conclude $A° \cap B°$ ⊂ $(A \cap B)°$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67244/discussion-between-maddude-and-a-smith).

Answer (score 2):

Use $x \in A^\circ \iff \exists r >0 : B(x,r) := \{ y\in X \mid d(x,y) < r \} \subset A$.

Comment: How can I show that $\exists r >0 : B(x,r) := \{ y\in X \mid d(x,y) \leq r \} \subset A$. I dont't have a difinied "d" in this case.

Comment: d is the metric of your metric space (X,d). can you clarify how you define interior points?

Comment: x is an interior point of a set A, if the set A is a neighbourhood of x.

Comment: so x lies in the interior if A contains an open ball B(x,r) centered around x, no?

Comment: yes but how can I show that A contains that open ball?

Comment: because we assumed $x \in A^\circ$. look again at the definition of neighbourhood in a metric space

Answer (score 1):

One definition of $A^\circ$ is the largest open set contained in $A$.

Using this definition, you can note that $A^\circ \cap B^\circ$ is an open set contained in $A \cap B$.

The other direction is similar but note that $A^\circ \cap B^\circ$
is an open set contained in both $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1):

In general one proves "A= B", for A and B sets, by showing that $A\subset B$ **and** $B\subset A$.  And one shows "$A\subset B$" by starting "if $x\in A$" and using the properties of A and B to conclude "then $x\in B$".

Here, to show $(A\cap B)^o= A^o\cap B^o$, start "if $x\in (A\cap B)^o$" then x is an interior point of $A\cap B$.  That is, there exist $\epsilon> 0$ such that all points, y, such that $d(x, y)< \epsilon$ are in $A\cap B$.  Such a y is in A so "there exist $\epsilon> 0$ such that if $d(x, y)< \epsilon$ then $y\in A$".  That is, x is in $A^o$.  The same argument, using B instead of A, shows that x is in $B^o$.  That is, $(A\cap B)^o\subset A^o\cap B^o.

Now go the other way: If "$x\in A^o\cap B^o$" then $x\in A^o$ and $x\in B^o$.  Since $x\in A_0$, there exist $\epsilon_1$ such that the set $\{y| d(x,y)< \epsilon_1\}$ is a subset of A.  Since $x\in B_0$, there exist $\epsilon_2$ such that the set $\{y| d(x,y)< \epsilon_2\}$ is a subset of B.  **Take $\epsilon$ equal t the *smaller* of $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$**.  Then $\{y|d(x,y)< \epsilon\}$ is a subset of both A and B so is a subset of $(A\cap B)$.  That means that $x\in (A\cap B)^o$.

Note, by the way, that this can be immediately extended to any finite collection of sets because any **finite** set of positive numbers contains a smallest positive number.  It does **not** extend to an infinite collection of sets because an infinite set of positive numbers does **not** necessarily contain a smallest positive number.